# Issues with Scikit-Image regionprops for multichannel intensity image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am attempting to extract region intensity for each color channel using the following:

```
props = regionprops_table(mask,intensity_image=img,
                          properties=['label',
                                      'area',
                                      'intensity_mean'])
```

However, I do not get multiple channels of intensity_mean. Does this multichannel function work (`scikit-image v0.20`), or am I doing something wrong?

I have tried to review documentation. This works on Windows, but not Mac.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an image. And a [mcve]. Posting both would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Please try v0.21, as this might have been fixed by this PR: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/6861